# “param is missing or the value is empty” in nested resource method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I'm trying to create a method called 'pack' under a resource called jobs.

My routes look like this:

```
  resources :jobs do
    member do
      get 'pack' => 'jobs#pack'
    end
  end
```

And the simplified version of my controller method looks like this.

```
def pack
    @job.pack
  end
```

And to get the pack, I have:

```
  before_action :set_job, only: %i[show edit update destroy pack]

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_job
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:description, :status, :client_id, :pack_size, :user_id)
  end
```

I'm able to hit my/end/point/jobs/1/pack and trigger the controller method, but I'm hitting the error:

> param is missing or the value is empty: job

Both the show and pack methods receive the save params:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
```

So I'm not really sure why only the #pack method is throwing me the missing job error. Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Console output:

```
Started GET "/api/v1/jobs/1/pack?user_id=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-11-20 19:57:24 +0800
Processing by JobsController#pack as HTML
  Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
  Job Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "jobs".* FROM "jobs" WHERE "jobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)



ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: job:
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:87:in `job_params'
  app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:6:in `pack'
```

Comment: can post `pack`  method that you have created inside model?(@pack.pack what it does?)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It should be @job.pack

Comment: yeah, can you add complete trace?

Comment: Trace is not particularly helpful, but editing into the question.

Comment: it's clearly saying mistake is at `job_params`. But we should find from where you called `job_params`? Tell me onething `@job.pack` here, `pack` is a method inside `Job` model?

Comment: can you show where are you doing the request? ajax or link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the first part of the `job_params` body.

You are requiring a `:job` in the `params.require(:job)`, but no `:job` is presented in the params:

```
Parameters: {"user_id"=>"1", "id"=>"1"}
```

So either you can remove the `require` part and just invoke the following in `job_params`:

```
params.permit(:description, :status, :client_id, :pack_size, :user_id, :id)
```

Note: I have added `:id` in the whitelist as I can see that being present too in the params.

Comment: Right, I understand that. What I don't understand is how the #show (/jobs/:id) method is able to process it but #pack (/jobs/:id/pack) cannot

Comment: can you share the exact 2 lines from `#show` and `#pack` which contain the invocation of params?